# ¿Cómo puedo convertir implicitamente esta llamada?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
MiModelo miModelo = Task.Run(async () => await MiModelo.GetPartnerAsync());
```

Pero me lanza el siguiente error

> No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo System.Threading.Tasks en NombreProyecto.Models.MiModelo

Por que sucede esto y como lo puedo resolver?

Intente conviertiendolo de la siguientes forma pero me seguia apareciendo el mensaje de error.

```
MiModelo miModelo = Task.Run(async () => await MiModelo.GetPartnerAsync() as MiModelo);


MiModelo miModelo = Task.Run(async () => (MiModelo) await MiModelo.GetPartnerAsync());
```

Comment: Por que usas Task.Run?

Comment: Por que estoy utilizándolo en un método void de un `ActionFilterAttribute ` el cual no podía convertir el async pero finalmente si lo logre. Aunque sigo con la duda de como poder convertir esa linea en el caso que vuelva a tener este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de hacer sincrónico un método `async` es usando  `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Tu código podría traducirse así:

```
MiModelo miModelo = await MiModelo.GetPartnerAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score -1):

Si tu método ya es asíncrono no hace falta ejecutarlo dentro de un `Task.Run` a menos que el método llamante no esté marcado como `async`. Te recomiendo lo devuelva la así

```
MiModelo miModelo = await MiModelo.GetPartnerAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Exacto, mi método no es `async` por eso lo llamo de esa forma.

Comment: Hola, conseguiste resolver la duda?

Comment: Si, tuve que convertir el método de llamada en `async` pero no era lo que quería en verdad, ya que necesitaba llamar a esa linea como `async` pero no al método de llamada.